# Drag a button in a ViewController - iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, drag-and-drop, calendar

What I'm trying to do is to drag a button and drop it into a "folder". 
But this "folder" is a day of a calendar, which is in a ViewController (I'm using Kal Calendar). 
So I dont know in which day is dropped, thats why im working with the position when dropped (a CGPoint).

I've already implemented the drag and drop. Also the perform selector for the action when dropped.

**Im looking for a code that can simulate a tap in the CGPoint position**

Hope you can help me figuring out how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the problem, using the drop location coordinates seams like a good way to determine on which date you dropped?

Comment: Im looking for a code that can simulate a click or a tap into a certain position.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wanna simulate a click at a certain point to see witch button gets called and by that way know which date?

I would suggest looping through the buttons and check if the CGPoint is within the CGRect of the button. Loop through every button until you get a hit, then you know the date!

Something like this:

```
-(int)dateFromPoint:(CGPoint)point;
{
    for(UIButton * button in arrayOfButtons)
    {

        CGRect frame = button.frame;
        if( // simple hit test :D
            (point.x >= frame.origin.x && point.x <= frame.origin.x+frame.size.width) &&
            (point.y >= frame.origin.y && point.y <= frame.origin.y+frame.size.height)
        )
        {
            // hit! return the date
            return button.whateverWayYouStoreTheDate;
        }
    }
    // no hit 
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this just now from the top of my head so there could be some errors, but you get the idea!